# YUI Library not working on SSL (secure server)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssl, https, yui

I use YUI Library for cropping image, but it works on http:// but not work on https://.
Any possible solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the protocols of `http` or `https`. Or i would say use the standard of `//` double leading slashes, it will decide on the basis of your application protocol. Such as:

```
<script src="//path/to/yui/lib.js"></script>
```